# get array_intersect count without duplicates php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have 2 arrays:

```
$first = array(1,1,2,3,4);
$second = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

when i use `$count = array_intersect($first, $second);`, and `count($count);` the matches, it shows 5, resulting in 1 intersecting twice. I need to get 4, which doesn't count duplicates.

how can I achieve that in php?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple: first make sure your arrays are unique, and then apply array_intersect:

```php
$count = count(array_intersect(array_unique($first), array_unique($second)));
```

Repro case on [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/PMYH6).

Comment: this is Great! I've figured it out another way by using array_diff(), but I will be using this to lessen my lines of code and I think this is way more efficient because it returns an integer. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Also, I would like to add these cone I've figured out before finding a better answer.

```
$result = array_intersect($first, $second);
  $diff = array_diff($result, $second);
   if(!empty($diff)) {
    $result = array_unique($result);
   }
```